# Erlang: Delete a map in a list of maps, then return the list

Tags: list, erlang, maps

I currently am working in the server side of my program and I'm looking for a way to eliminate a certain map right after I discover it has the atom I was searching for.

The following code can succesfully find if the map with the atom exists in the list of maps, but I'm looking for a way to delete that map from the list and return the whole list without the map I just deleted.

"Asistente" is the atom I'm looking for.
L_Asistente is the list of maps itself

First method is when you covered the entire list and didn't find the atom in the list of maps.

The second is the search itself. Currently, It will return true when it finds its target, but I want to change that into the whole list minus the map that had the atom I was searching for.

```
server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(_, []) ->
    false;

server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
    [MapAsistente | Rest] = L_Asistentes,
    io:format("~p == ~p ~n", [MapAsistente, Asistente]),
    case maps:get("clave",MapAsistente) == Asistente of
        true ->
            true;
        false -> 
            server_checaExistenciaAsistente(Asistente, Rest)
    end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to use the accumulator:

```
server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(_, [], Acc) ->
    Acc;

server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, [MapAsistente | Rest], Acc) ->
    io:format("~p == ~p ~n", [MapAsistente, Asistente]),
    case maps:find("clave", MapAsistente) of
        {ok, _} ->
            server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, Rest, Acc);
        error -> 
            server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, Rest, lists:append(Acc, [MapAsistente]))
    end.
```

Result:

```
#{"abc" => 1,"clave" => a1} == #{"abc" => 1,"clave" => a1}
#{"abc" => 2,"clave1" => a2} == #{"abc" => 1,"clave" => a1}
#{"abc" => 3,"clave2" => a3} == #{"abc" => 1,"clave" => a1}
#{"abc" => 4,"clave3" => a4} == #{"abc" => 1,"clave" => a1}
[#{"abc" => 2,"clave1" => a2},
 #{"abc" => 3,"clave2" => a3},
 #{"abc" => 4,"clave3" => a4}]
```

You want to do this?

Comment: How would I initialize Acc? With an empty list, right?

Comment: `server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Abc, List, [])`

Comment: Pass Acc as is empty list

Comment: Alright this worked and it's actually functional and recursive unlike the other answer, which seems more fitting to me. I did the following modifications though

http://pastebin.com/WYfCHE0F

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a [list comprehension](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#list-comprehensions) where you check for the non-existence of the key you are looking for:

```
server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
    [MapAsistente || MapAsistente <- L_Asistentes,
         maps:find("clave", MapAsistente) =/= {ok, Asistente}].
```

A more modular approach is to allow for a custom filter condition:

```
server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
    filter(L_Asistentes, fun(M) -> maps:find("clave", M) =/= {ok, Asistente} end).

filter(Maps, Filter) ->
    [Map || Map <- Maps, Filter(Map)].
```

Comment: Good answer, but the man apparently just beginning to learn Erlang, so can not understand what's going on here :)

Comment: True. Added a link to the Learn You Some Erlang chapter on list comprehensions.

Comment: Alright it worked. So let me get this straight.

You use a "for" esque function to go throw the list and check each map, then you start comparing.

Now the part I didn't understand is HOW you made it get filtered.

Comment: @user3651164, `for map in maps include in results list if condition is true`  In the first case, true/false is returned for the condition by the maps:find() function.  The `,` is an `if-esque` construct. In the second case, *all the work* to create the results list is shuttled to a helper function, which could have been named `get_results()`.  The helper function needs two args to construct the results: 1) A list of maps, 2) a *predicate* function that takes one argument and returns true if the map should be included in the results list....(continued)

Comment: ...Inside the helper function, you have the same *list comprehension* structure as in the first case: `for map in maps include in results list if condition is true`, and this time true/false is returned by a function that was passed into the helper function and stored in the Filter variable.

Comment: @user3651164 Anything that returns a boolean value after the generator (the `|| X <- Y` part will act as a filter on the elements, only including them if the value is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
>     [MapAsistente || MapAsistente <- L_Asistentes,
>          maps:find("clave", MapAsistente) =/= {ok, Asistente}].
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
>     filter(L_Asistentes, fun(M) -> maps:find("clave", M) =/= {ok, Asistente} end).
>
> filter(Maps, Filter) ->
>     [Map || Map <- Maps, Filter(Map)].
> ```
>
> So let me get this straight. You use a "for" esque function to go
>   throw the list and check each map, then you start comparing. Now the
>   part I didn't understand is HOW you made it get filtered.

In `python`, a list comprehension is a little more readable:

```
results = [Map for Map in Maps if “clave” in Map]
```

And, if you wanted you could extract the if condition into a function:

```
def yes_or_no(Map):
    if 'clave’ in Map:
        return True
    else:
        return False

results = [Map for Map in Maps if yes_or_no(Map)]
```

Note that `yes_or_no()` takes one argument and returns True or False.

Here are the two `erlang examples` you wondered about:

1)

```
server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
    [MapAsistente || MapAsistente <- L_Asistentes,
         maps:find("clave", MapAsistente) =/= {ok, Asistente}].
```

If you make these substitutions:

```
|| ... for  
<- ... in
,  ... if
```

then you would get a python list comprehension:

```
[MapAsistente for MapAsistente in L_Asistentes if
         maps:find("clave", MapAsistente) =/= {ok, Asistente}].
```

So you can see that in erlang list comprehensions, the `,` is an if-esque construct.  In this case, `maps:find()` returns true/false, which determines if the Map will be included in the results list, similar to `yes_or_no()` in the python list comprehension.

2)

```
server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
    filter(L_Asistentes, fun(M) -> maps:find("clave", M) =/= {ok, Asistente} end).

filter(Maps, Filter) ->
    [Map || Map <- Maps, Filter(Map)].
```

In this case, rather than using a list comprehension to compute the results inside `server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente()`, all the work to create the results list is shuttled to a helper function, which could have been named get_results():

```
server_checaExistenciaBorrarAsistente(Asistente, L_Asistentes) ->
    get_results(...).

get_results(Maps, Filter) ->
    [Map || Map <- Maps, Filter(Map)].
```

In python, that list comprehension would look like this:

```
[Map for Map in Maps if Filter(Map)]
```

The helper function, `get_results()`, needs two args to construct the results:

1. A list of Maps.
2. A function that takes one argument and returns true or false to indicate whether the Map should be included in the results list--just like the python `yes_or_no()` function.

Inside `get_results()`, you have the same list comprehension structure as in the first case:

```
[Map || Map <- Maps, Filter(Map)]
```

But this time, true/false is determined by a function that was passed into the helper function and stored in the Filter variable.

If it helps, here is a really simple example:

```
func() ->
    my_helper(fun lists:reverse/1).

my_helper(SomeFunc) ->
    SomeFunc([1 , 2, 3]).
```

Example:

```
9> c(my).
{ok,my}
10> my:func().   
[3,2,1]
```